# Setting focus on a window in opencv

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to open a window in opencv (with imshow) and focussing the window so that the user can directly give an input to the window. The first time I open a window this works, but after calling destroyAllWindows and then reopening a new window, the focus is not set to this window
How can I force opencv to focus on this special window?

Thanks